# How to use any() function with *args in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to master any() and all() functions in python.
I am trying to write a code which checks if user has entered any non-numeric value.

```
def my_sum(*args):
    #args=[]
    if any([(type(arg)==int or type(arg)==float) for arg in args]):
        total=0
        for num in args:
            total+=(num)
        return total
    else:
        return "Please enter numerals only"
print (my_sum(1,45,87,36))
print (my_sum(1,25,45,75.85,"Newton","Pythagoras"))
```

I expected that first call will print out  sum of all numbers, while second function call to print message.But I am getting type error message of unsupported operand types.

Answer (score 0):

`any()` will return True when at least one of the elements is True. This is the case in both test cases - you will never execute the `else` part.
`all()` will return True only if all elements are True. So in this case that is what you want - use `all()`, not `any()`.

As a side note, to test for type, as recommended in PEP8 better use `isinstance()`, not `type()`, e.g. `isinstance(x, (int, float))`

Finally, it's considered more pythonic to use try/except to catch the error and handle it, instead of type checking.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your condition to be either one of these:

`# This is checking if all input in list are floats or ints
if all([(type(arg)==int or type(arg)==float) for arg in args]):`

Or

`# This is checking if any input in list is NOT an int or float
if any([(type(arg)!=int or type(arg)!=float) for arg in args]):`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using **any()**, as well as leaving the sequence of the **if** statement unchanged, then you might better check for **str** types and use **not**:

```
def my_sum(*args):
    # if none of the args are str, then sum them up
    if not any([type(arg)==str for arg in args]):
        total=0
        for num in args:
            total+=num
        return total
     # otherwise return the message
    else:
        return "Please enter numerals only"
print (my_sum(1,45,87,36))
print (my_sum(1,25,45,75.85,"Newton","Pythagoras"))
```

However it feels somewhat more logical to get rid of the **not**, and rather to change the sequence of the **if else** statement:

```
def my_sum(*args):
    # if any of the args are string, then return the message
    if any([type(arg)==str for arg in args]):
        return "Please enter numerals only"
    # otherwise sum them up
    else:
        total = 0
        for num in args:
            total += num
        return total
print (my_sum(1,45,87,36))
print (my_sum(1,25,45,75.85,"Newton","Pythagoras"))
```